# How to handle incoming call events in Android

Tags: android, events, phone-call

Does anybody know if there is any event to handle incoming calls?
I'm developing an app that streams audio from the microphone and I would like to have a listener that stops the recording, etc when there is an incoming call, and that restarts the process when the telephone call is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `BroadcastReceiver` and listen for the [`TelephonyManager#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED) action.