# Application / service that handle incoming calls

Tags: android, phone-call

Which android OS application / service is handling incoming calls.
I assume  that there will be some hardware interrupts received for an incoming call.
But ultimately there must be a software that get invoked and launches the screen to answer the call.

I was assuming it is some services. But when I see the running services, I do not see any to handle this.
Please explain how android handles incoming calls.

Comment: googling your question gave me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137582/how-to-handle-incoming-call-events-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779991/how-to-accept-an-incoming-call-by-clicking-a-button and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716481/handling-incoming-call-in-android-programming

Comment: Thanks for your apply. These links say how from an application incoming calls can be get notified. My point is which app in android is handling it. I mean the system service / app.